# Trying to understand float and text

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to understand how float works with different elements. The first example have 2 `<div>` which is floated to `left` with one of the div having some text. As expected, both are placed next to each other horizontally.

[Example 1](https://codepen.io/pranesh-r/pen/WLJEYv?editors=1100)

The second example have the same setup except that the last `<div>` with text is not floated to left. Now, I was expecting that `<div>` to go underneath the first floated `<div>`. But, the result is different. The second `<div>` went beneath the first `<div>` but the text is placed under the first `<div>`.

[Example 2](https://codepen.io/pranesh-r/pen/LMmjMr?editors=1100)

Can anyone explain me what's happening?

Comment: let me know if the duplicates are enough detailed so that you understand what is happening

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Because `overflow` happens for yellow div and default is `overflow: visible`, text inside the yellow div creates a new block formatting context.
[Overflow docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)
[Block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)